# How to define shortcut key for Reindent on sublimetext 3

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'm on Ubuntu and I'd like to make a shortcut key for `Edit > Line > Reindent`.

I've seen the [docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html) but could not figure out where to put the json definition. So appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how you can add this shortcut in Sublime:

1. Go to Preferences > Key Bindings-User
2. Add the below key value pairs to the existing JSON array (mostly it would be empty previously):

   ```
   { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "reindent"}
   ```

To make this shortcut work, you need to have the syntax highlighter plugin already installed for the particular programming language you are using.

Comment: for me it doesn't work,  it opens a list of command ... here's my key bindings : `{
    "keys": ["f5"], "command": "revert",
  "keys": ["ctrl+alt+t"], "command": "time_stamp",
  "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "reindent"
}`

Comment: worked perfectly

Comment: user130482 each shortcut is its own line with curly brackets `{}` separated by commas. Here is mine for example:
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+'"], "command": "change_quotes" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "reindent"}